# How to get a reference to the list in an ngfor with a pipe applied to it

Tags: angular

I am applying a filter to a list inside an ngfor like so `*ngFor="data | pipe"` I want access to the object that gets outputted from the filter in my ts component class. I tried using this: `*ngFor="data | pipe as filtereddata"`, but I think that only works relative to the tag and doesn't seem to get applied to the object on the component. Is there a way to get access to this filtered data?

For reference the pipe does a sort and a filter and I want to be able to select the first item in the list and I don't want to have to resort the data in the ts if it's already being done.

Comment: just gona comment that you should NOT be sorting OR filtering in a pipe in angular. pipes run on every change detection cycle, whether anything has changed or not.  This means potentially heavy sort and filter operations run every single change detection cycle, which results in very poor app performance.  The best practice is to build the logic for when to sort and filter yourself in your ts component class instead of relying on change detection to do it for you, it also has the side effect of solving your problem.

Comment: I'm not using an impure pipe so it should only run when needed so I don't see why what you're saying would be true

Comment: how are you sorting or filtering without an impure pipe,

Comment: That would only work if you’re consistently changing the object references every time the list changes and your sort / filter parameters are primitives. Or if the list doesn’t change. Option1 just doesn’t make any sense to me because it seems easier to just apply the sort / filter in component when needed, and if anyone else ever works on this app or if you did this in a team environment, no one would understand why. Option2, same case. This is somewhat opinion, but you shouldn’t have to understand the inner workings of a pipe to use it.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you to keep the sorting and filtering in the .ts and not via Pipe. Then you could have the reference to your sorted/filtered list and even debounce the filter easier than using pipe

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put your sorting logic in a property with getter in your ts. Something like:

```
get sortedData(): any[] {
    return ...your sorting logic...
}
```

Than do the ngFor through this sortedData property.

Note: return type from the getter could be you specific type ( e.g. YourType[] )

I hope this will help you

Comment: This is not really a great idea because binding data to a function causes that function to keep running to check the data hasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

```
import { TestPipe } from 'ts file location'

@Component({
selector:'YourComponent',
templateURl:'Component Html Path'
})
export class ComponentClassName implements OnInit{
private formattedData: any;
constructor(private pipe: TestPipe, private service:yourService){}
ngOnInit(){
//Service call to fetch data
this.service.getData().subscribe((data) =>{

    this.formattedData = this.pipe.transform(data); // use formattedData to bind in HTML

})
}
}
```

formattedData will have reference in your component file.  You can apply the transform in a separate function and invoke it every time the array changes

Comment: This is what I'm doing, but I'd rather use the pipe in html so I don't have to keep changing the data manually